# tensorflow - tf.keras.Model.fit causes run out of data for validation data with validation_steps being set

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning

Trying to understand the `validation_steps` parameter of [tf.keras.Model.fit](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/Model#fit).

> Total number of steps (batches of samples) to draw before stopping when performing validation at the end of every epoch.

For instance, [TFDS MNIST](https://www.tensorflow.org/datasets/catalog/mnist) dataset has `60,000` train and `10,000` test data records. Trying to consume all the records during `num_epochs=2` epochs with `batch_size=8` using generators as the data sources to the model.

```
(train, test), info = tfds.load(
    'mnist',
    split=['train', 'test'],
    shuffle_files=True,
    as_supervised=True,
    with_info=True,
)

x_generator = train.batch(batch_size).as_numpy_iterator()
v_generator = test.batch(batch_size).as_numpy_iterator()   # using 'test' for validation here
```

The training data can afford `3750=(60000 / batch_size=8 / epochs=2)` batches, and the test data can afford `625=(10000 / batch_size=8 / epochs=2)` batches.

```
def f(image, label):
    return 1

num_total_train_records = len(list(        # 60000
    train.map(f)
))
num_total_test_records = len(list(         # 10000
    test.map(f)
))
print(num_total_train_records, num_total_test_records)
-----
60000 10000
```

```
num_epochs = 2
batch_size = 8

num_x_batches_per_epoch = int(np.floor(num_total_train_records / batch_size / num_epochs))
num_v_batches_per_epoch = int(np.floor(num_total_test_records / batch_size / num_epochs)) 
print(num_x_batches_per_epoch, num_v_batches_per_epoch)
# ---
# show 3750 625
```

However, setting `tf.keras.Model.fit(validation_steps=625)` causes the error `` Your input ran out of data... Make sure that your dataset or generator can generate at least `steps_per_epoch * epochs` batches (in this case, 625 batches) ``.

```
model.fit(
    x=x_generator ,
    epochs=num_epochs,
    batch_size=batch_size,    # not using batch_size arg makes no difference
    steps_per_epoch=num_x_batches_per_epoch,
    validation_data=v_generator,
    validation_steps=num_v_batches_per_epoch,
    validation_batch_size=batch_size
)
```

```
Your input ran out of data; interrupting training. 
Make sure that your dataset or generator can generate at least `steps_per_epoch * epochs` batches 
(in this case, 625 batches). You may need to use the repeat() function when building your dataset.

2023-11-21 17:39:33.226528: I tensorflow/core/framework/local_rendezvous.cc:421] Local rendezvous recv item cancelled. Key hash: 17391114698345974101
2023-11-21 17:39:33.226580: I tensorflow/core/framework/local_rendezvous.cc:421] Local rendezvous recv item cancelled. Key hash: 8226056677969075330
WARNING:tensorflow:Your input ran out of data; interrupting training. Make sure that your dataset or generator can generate at least `steps_per_epoch * epochs` batches (in this case, 625 batches). You may need to use the repeat() function when building your dataset.
```

### Code

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
import tensorflow_datasets as tfds


(train, test), info = tfds.load(
    'mnist',
    split=['train', 'test'],
    shuffle_files=True,
    as_supervised=True,
    with_info=True,
)


def f(image, label):
    return 1

num_total_train_records = len(list(
    train.map(f)
))
num_total_test_records = len(list(
    test.map(f)
))
print(num_total_train_records, num_total_test_records)

model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
  tf.keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape=(28, 28)),
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, activation='relu'),
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(10)
])
model.compile(
    optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(0.001),
    loss=tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True),
    metrics=[tf.keras.metrics.SparseCategoricalAccuracy()],
)

num_epochs = 2
batch_size = 8

num_x_batches_per_epoch = int(np.floor(num_total_train_records / batch_size / num_epochs))
num_v_batches_per_epoch = int(np.floor(num_total_test_records / batch_size / num_epochs)) 
print(num_x_batches_per_epoch, num_v_batches_per_epoch)
# ---
# will show 3750 625


x_generator = train.batch(batch_size).as_numpy_iterator()
v_generator = test.batch(batch_size).as_numpy_iterator()

model.fit(
    x=x_generator ,
    epochs=num_epochs,
    batch_size=batch_size,
    steps_per_epoch=num_x_batches_per_epoch,
    validation_data=v_generator,
    validation_steps=num_v_batches_per_epoch,
    validation_batch_size=batch_size
)
```

By minus 1, it works.

```
num_v_batches_per_epoch = int(np.floor(num_total_test_records / batch_size / num_epochs)) -1  # Cuase ran out of data without -1
```

Please help understand this behavior. Also the document says `Only relevant if validation_data is provided and is a tf.data dataset.` but obviously it is not only for `tf.data.Dataset`.

### Environment

```
tensorflow 2.14.1
Python 3.10.12
Ubuntu 22.04 LTS
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all you are computing the steps wrong, you don't divide by the number of epochs at all just the data size to the batch size, because the steps are the number of fetched batches per each epoch:

```
num_x_batches_per_epoch = int(np.floor(num_total_train_records / batch_size))
num_v_batches_per_epoch = int(np.floor(num_total_test_records / batch_size))
```

Second you are using a Tensorflow dataset objects

```
(train, test), info = tfds.load
```

so not a custom generator, so you don't specify the steps for training or validation.

Check this tutorial:
https://www.tensorflow.org/datasets/keras_example

Comment: or simply `num_total_train_records // batch_size` ;)

Comment: Thannks for the answer. Sorry that I could have explained clearly. I want to test how to use generator and steps_per_epoch, hence did the strange stuff of converting TFDS dataset to generator.

Answer (score 0):

Specifically for `tfds` datasets, you can get the number of total observations with `with_info=True` like you did.

```
import tensorflow_datasets as tfds
import tensorflow as tf

(train, test), info = tfds.load(
    'mnist',
    split=['train', 'test'],
    shuffle_files=True,
    as_supervised=True,
    with_info=True,
)

num_total_train_records = info.splits['train'].num_examples
num_total_test_records = info.splits['test'].num_examples
```

Then, to create the correct `steps_per_epoch`, you can use the floor division operator to get the correct number of batches:

```
num_x_batches_per_epoch = num_total_train_records // batch_size
num_v_batches_per_epoch = num_total_test_records // batch_size
```

Complete example:

```
import tensorflow_datasets as tfds
import tensorflow as tf
(train, test), info = tfds.load(
    'mnist',
    split=['train', 'test'],
    shuffle_files=True,
    as_supervised=True,
    with_info=True,
)
num_total_train_records = info.splits['train'].num_examples
num_total_test_records = info.splits['test'].num_examples

model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
  tf.keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape=(28, 28)),
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, activation='relu'),
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(10)
])
model.compile(
    optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(0.001),
    loss=tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True),
    metrics=[tf.keras.metrics.SparseCategoricalAccuracy()],
)

num_epochs = 2
batch_size = 8

num_x_batches_per_epoch = num_total_train_records // batch_size
num_v_batches_per_epoch = num_total_test_records // batch_size 
x_generator = train.batch(batch_size).as_numpy_iterator()
v_generator = test.batch(batch_size).as_numpy_iterator()
model.fit(
    x=x_generator ,
    epochs=num_epochs,
    batch_size=batch_size,
    steps_per_epoch=num_x_batches_per_epoch,
    validation_data=v_generator,
    validation_steps=num_v_batches_per_epoch,
    validation_batch_size=batch_size
)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer and allow me to ask? The generator can only provide num_total_train_records records which the model.fit needs to consume over 2 epochs. So one epoch can only consume num_total_train_records / 2 records?

Comment: No because the iterator is restarted at every epoch

Comment: I am afraid the code above cause the same error. Perhaps kindly run the code on your environment and let me know the result?